# REST: pass a BigDecimal value in pathparam

Tags: rest, api, restful-url, path-parameter

how to pass a BigDecimal value in pathparam in browser URL?

```
    @GET
    @Path("helloxyz/{par1}/{par2}")
    @Produces{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public  helloxyz(@PathParam("par1") BigDecimal par1,@PathParam("par2") BigDecimal par2){

    BigDecimal result = par1.divide(par2)

    return result;

    }

}
```

I am receiving error like can't extract parameter from http request.

when I pass values like this.

```
http://xxlocalhostaddressxx/rest/app/helloxyz/{"par1" : 1.2}/{"par2" : 1.2}/
```

However, everything works file for `@PathParam`type `String`. only happens in the case of non String type `@PathParam`

Comment: If i were You I would just use String. Generally it's good practise to initialize BigDecimal with String. You have to only check if passed format is correct

Comment: you are right.. and that's what I did  :) Thanks anyways!!